# register a public api route in laravel nova without authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

I am developing a card for Laravel nova.

As part of this, I want an API route that can be posted, but I don't want to have to authenticate against it.

I have registered my route in the card's api.php

```
 Route::post('/endpoint/{id}', function (Request $request, $id) {)
```

This works if I call it with an already authenticated session.

But if I try to call it from postman I get

`HTTP 419 Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again.`

I can see that the card service provider is registering the route as so

```
Route::middleware(['nova'])
        ->prefix('nova-vendor/NovaPusherCard')
        ->group(__DIR__.'/../routes/api.php');
```

So I guess that Nova is putting some authenticated in front of the route.

Is there a way I can register the route without adding authentication?

Answer (score 1):

ok so I worked it out.

I just needed to update the middleware to api instead of nova.